# How to update the expression value on a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression

I am passing the expression

```
InsertAsync(caseCommentDto, e => e.CaseNumber == caseCommentDto.CaseNumber && e.CommentSequenceNumber == caseCommentDto.CommentSequenceNumber)
```

to my gateway method

```
public async Task<BaseResult> InsertAsync(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
        //Get SequenceID for example CaseNumber

        var sequenceIdField = typeof(SequenceIds).GetField(typeof(TEntity).Name).GetValue(null);
        var sequenceField = typeof(Sequences).GetField(typeof(TEntity).Name).GetValue(null);
        var entityType = typeof(TEntity).Name;
        var sequenceIdValue = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(sequenceIdField.ToString())?.GetValue(entity);
        var sequenceNumber = _amhUnitOfWork.GetNextSequenceAsync(sequenceIdValue.ToString()).Result.Payload;
        typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(sequenceField.ToString())?.SetValue(entity, sequenceNumber);

        //var parma = expression.(sequenceNumber.ToString()).
        //expression = { expression=>}
        //someList.Select(x => { x.SomeProp = "foo"; return x; })
        //expression.Update();SetProperty();e
        //expression.Parameters.
        //SetProperty(expression,sequenceField.ToString(), sequenceIdValue);
        typeof(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>).GetField(sequenceField.ToString())?.SetValue(expression, sequenceNumber);

        return await _amhUnitOfWork.InsertAsync(entity, expression).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

everything here is dynamically determined. i have been able to set the value of **entity** with code.

```
typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(sequenceField.ToString())?.SetValue(entity, sequenceNumber);
```

how do I do the same for **predicate**.

This seems to be working, not sure though, I am not able to verify. How do I verify if this is working.

```
typeof(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>).GetField(sequenceField.ToString())?.SetValue(expression, sequenceNumber);
```

Edit: Confirming that the above is not working.

Comment: You have to use an expression visitor to visit each node in your expression and rewrite the required values. But this whole implementation seems anti patternish as you are using reflection heavily to accomplish something that abstraction could do without reflection.

Comment: Are you using EF?

Comment: @AvinKavish yes

Comment: EF will automatically update sequences when you insert a record

Comment: If your code works and you can insert a record successfully it works. But it won't because: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/expression-trees

Comment: It seems that I have to use expression visitor as suggested by @Avin Kavish. Any idea on how to use visitor in this scenario.